# Finding all "essential" packages with apt

Tags: apt

When I run synaptic, there are certain packages which synaptic treats as "essential". For example, if I select bash for removal, I will be warned that bash is an "essential package". If I then press the apply button I get a list of packages that are going to be acted on. One of those lists is the list of essential packages that I am about to remove.

Using the apt toolset, how can I vgenerate a list of all the packages that synaptic considers essential?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can list all essential packages using `aptitude search '?essential'` or `dpkg-query -Wf '${Package;-40}${Essential}\n' | grep yes`.

Additionally there are also several packages with priority *required* that you shouldn't remove, too: `dpkg-query -Wf '${Package;-40}${Priority}\n' | grep -E "required"`

For your information, [Essential](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Essential) and [Priority](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Priority) are fields in the control file of a package.

Comment: Why [`apt list`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt-patterns.7.en.html)/`aptitude search` `'?essential'`/`~E` include `apt` but `dpkg-query` alternative doesn't? [Isn't dpkg-query](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04.en.html) the correct output?

Answer (score 6):

```
aptitude search ~E
```

for other search patterns you can look in [aptitude doc](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html).

Answer (score 2):

- for daily use: `apt list ?essential` or `apt list ~E`
- for script: `apt-cache show ~E | grep -Po '(?<=^Package: ).*'`

`?essential` and `~E` are documented in [apt-patterns(7)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man7/apt-patterns.7.html), available on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Debian 11.